# perforce: how to check files that been modified recently (for the half year period) and who modify those files

Tags: perforce, p4v

In perforce, how can I check

1. Files that been modified recently (half year or one year period)?
2. Who modify the files?

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to know, say, the files that changed in the last six months of 2019:

```
p4 files //...@2019/07/07:00:00:00,@2019/12/31:23:59:59
```

To include users:

```
p4 filelog //...@2019/07/07:00:00:00,@2019/12/31:23:59:59
```